# imread devuelve none (opencv y python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

tengo el siguiente código en dónde lo único que quiero hacer es abrir una imagen pero la función `imread` me retorna el valor `none`, ya me fijado en la ruta, nombre y extensión del archivo y son correctos:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('123.png')

print(img)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Intentaste usando el path absoluto? Como `C:/carpeta/carpeta2/123.png` (nota que uso forwardslash / en lugar de backslash \ porque Python usa el backslash como carácter de escape)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba verificando la ruta en un if

```
import cv2
from pathlib import Path

my_file = Path("123.png")
if my_file.is_file():
    img = cv2.imread('123.png')
    print(img)
else:
    print('La imagen no existe')
```

También intenta probando con otra imagen si esto no funciona.

Comment: hola, lo resolvi pero no me gusta como quedo, tuve que escribir la ruta absoluta, por alguna razon no me deja usar ruta relativa, gracias por responder

Comment: mmmm la verdad no tuve ese problema, pero tal vez podrías utilizar `os.getcwd()`para obtener la ruta desde donde llamas a la imagen y concatenarlo con la ruta que necesitas.